# Can't get on exit modal window to work (conflict)

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Im currently trying to implement a simple modal window when the visitor wants to close the browser window using this little [script](http://tonylea.com/go/examples/jquery-exit-popup/).

Now when i implement into [my page](http://luukratief-design.nl/sim/).  It simply does not work.

I am not a coder but i tried to debug a bit and found out that the conflict is somewhere in this file: `<script type="text/javascript" src="tabs.js"></script>`

To be a little more precise i think it is because of `tpj.noConflict();`

That file is needed for the slider to load and for the tabs to work.
If i delete that line, the modal works, but ofcourse the tabs and slider don't.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the initialization function stated in your listed example, instead; try using this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ) {
    jQ.noConflict();
    jQ(document).mousemove(function(e) {

        jQ('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - jQ('#exitpopup').width()/2));
        jQ('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 - jQ('#exitpopup').height()/2));

        if(e.pageY <= 5)
        {

            // Show the exit popup
            jQ('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
            jQ('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
        }

    });

    jQ('#exitpopup_bg').click(function(){
        jQ('#exitpopup_bg').fadeOut();
        jQ('#exitpopup').slideUp();
    });

});
```

This should handle the conflict if it actually is.